# Configure CORS for Spring Cloud Gateway using react not working

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a React application which is running locally with a Spring Cloud Gateway. I get this error:

```
adminLogin:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9191/admin/authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed.
```

9191 is my cloud gateway port number
My yml file of cloud gateway:

```
server:
  port: 9191

spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:3000/"
            allowedMethods:
            - GET
            - POST
            - PUT
            - DELETE
        
      routes:
        - id: ADMIN-SERVICE
          uri: lb://ADMIN-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/admin/**
        - id: CUSTOMER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://CUSTOMER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/customer/**
        - id: DEALER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://DEALER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/dealer/**
        - id: VENUE-SERVICE
          uri: lb://VENUE-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/venue/**
      

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue with react app. Seems like you are missing default-filters.
I have fixed using below config for cors in spring cloud gateway :-

```
    spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
      routes:
        - id: portalModule
```

Spring-Boot v2.7.4,
Java v11,
Spring-cloud-version v2021.0.4